# CSS transform translate not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const openBtn = document.querySelector('.open')
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close')
const navContainer = document.querySelector('.nav-container')

openBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    openBtn.classList.add('hide')
    closeBtn.classList.remove('hide')
    navContainer.classList.remove('.show-nav')
})

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    closeBtn.classList.add('hide')
    openBtn.classList.remove('hide')
    navContainer.classList.add('.show-nav')
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-btn{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hide{
    display: none;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.show-nav{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
h1{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
h1 span{
    color: cornflowerblue;
}
.links{
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.links a{
    line-height: 48px;
}
.social{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.social a{
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="nav-btn open">
        <i class="fas fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="nav-btn close hide">
        <i class="fas fa-times fa-3x"></i>
    </button>
    <nav class="nav-container">
        <h1>
            Side
            <span>
                Bar
            </span>
        </h1>
        <ul class="links">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contacts</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="social">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-github fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I was trying to make a sidebar with html css and javascript. I've had a problem with the sidebar not appearing. I want the to make the sidebar appear by adding a '.show-nav' class that resets the the '.nav-container' transform translate back to 0%. The '.show-nav' class is being added but the properties that it contains doesn't update the Style.

Comment: you're adding `.show-nav` rather than `show-nav` as the class

Answer (score 0):

There was some errors in your code like `navContainer.classList.remove('.show-nav')`, note the dot in the remove method. Also, there are some inconsistences in your css.

```js
const openBtn = document.querySelector('.open')
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close')
const navContainer = document.querySelector('.nav-container')

openBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    openBtn.classList.add('hide')
    closeBtn.classList.remove('hide')
    navContainer.classList.add('show-nav')
})

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    closeBtn.classList.add('hide')
    openBtn.classList.remove('hide')
    navContainer.classList.remove('show-nav')
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-btn{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hide{
    display: none;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: pink;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.show-nav{
    transform: translateX(-10%);
}
h1{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
h1 span{
    color: cornflowerblue;
}
.links{
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.links a{
    line-height: 48px;
}
.social{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.social a{
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="nav-btn open">
        <i class="fas fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="nav-btn close hide">
        <i class="fas fa-times fa-3x"></i>
    </button>
    <nav class="nav-container">
        <h1>
            Side
            <span>
                Bar
            </span>
        </h1>
        <ul class="links">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contacts</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="social">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-github fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just  fixed it.

Comment: You're welcome. Please, check the answer as correct if it was util for you.

Answer (score 0):

remove te "." into your `classList.add` and `.remove`. you dont need the class identifier because you are already declaring it. also upon testing your code, i found out that you cannot close the side nav. thats because the width extends to the full width of the page covering up your close button. you can fix it by reducing its width or by adding this code as i have done in this snippet

```
button {
    z-index: 10
}
```

```js
const openBtn = document.querySelector('.open')
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close')
const navContainer = document.querySelector('.nav-container')

openBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    openBtn.classList.add('hide')
    closeBtn.classList.remove('hide')
    navContainer.classList.add('show-nav')
})

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    closeBtn.classList.add('hide')
    openBtn.classList.remove('hide')
    navContainer.classList.remove('show-nav')
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-btn{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hide{
    display: none;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav-container{
    display: flex;
    background: blue;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.show-nav{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
h1{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
h1 span{
    color: cornflowerblue;
}
.links{
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.links a{
    line-height: 48px;
}
.social{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.social a{
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-left: 24px;
}

button {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="nav-btn open">
        <i class="fas fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="nav-btn close hide">
        <i class="fas fa-times fa-3x"></i>
    </button>
    <nav class="nav-container">
        <h1>
            Side
            <span>
                Bar
            </span>
        </h1>
        <ul class="links">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contacts</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="social">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fab fa-github fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```